# How to create shapefile from text file with multiple headers using arcpy?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, point, text

I found various examples but nothing like what I'm looking for. I seem to be able to do it if I format it in a specific way but it doesn't let me add NAME and LOCID.

My ultimate goal is to create a point shapefile from this list:

[image: This is what my text file looks like]

Comment: @OBMGIS have you same keys in all lines?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A question asking how to do something in arcpy should show your own attempt, and details of what happens when you try it.  Please [edit] your question to include a snippet of your arcpy code attempt and info on what does/doesn't happen when you run it including any error messages.

Comment: @OBMGIS you might need to split your question in two.  One for how to convert your text file into a CSV or table with a single header line (probably best asked on [so]) and then one to take that result and create your points.

Comment: Your first step is going to have to be to remove all the prefixes ('ID:', etc.) from the file. You can do that with search-and-replace in a text editor.

Comment: @DanC my response do a valid csv to import this file. search and replace can crash file if a key exist in values...

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten That's possible, but based on the visible portion of the file, I think it would be fine to search on " X: " and replace it with nothing. Or you could import it as a CSV as it is and once it's in a table, strip out however many leading characters from each field.

Comment: @DanC in fact i prefer a small script by experience because i can automate the process. If he add lot of file, he can loop on folder to set a batch trasnformation. If the process is oneshot your approch can be easiest for a person without experience in development. But he mentioned arcpy.

Answer (score 2):

Use pandas lib if keys are in same order and you have same keys in all lines to generate a valid csv

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",|:", header=None,  skipinitialspace=True) # set separators , and : and remove initial space
df2 =df.ix[:,1::2]
df2.columns = list(df.ix[0,0::2])
df2.to_csv("data_new.csv", encoding="utf-8")
```

you can ignore last line and also complete this to generate XY Event layer with arcpy.

Comment: If you are converting it to a csv yourself, I don't see the need for you to downvote my answer, when it answers the question.

Comment: @VijayRamesh because it's necessary to create a valid csv or Dataframe before generate add it on a software as layer. In fact in key subject there is arcpy and this is python lin not R and Arcgis desktop. Sorry for your incomprehension

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten Does this account for the leading spaces?  e.g.  `ID: 1, Name: Hyder` has a space between the comma and the name

Comment: @Midavalo for that you need add  skipinitialspace=True has parameter in read_csv method. I update part script

Answer (score -2):

Two answers:

Both involve converting your text file to a .CSV format as show below.

[image]

1) Load this in ArcMap and Add XY Data > Export as Shapefile

2) You can load this in R and write shapefile using maptools.

```
library(maptools)
library(sp)
trial <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\rameshv\\Desktop\\trial.csv", header=T)
coordinates(trial) <- ~LONG+LAT
writeSpatialShape(trial, "C:\\Users\\rameshv\\Desktop\\trial")
```

Both work.

Comment: You have not read the question correctly and don't take in consideration the exemple of datafile

Comment: @GeoStoneMarten I think this is probably one of the easiest solutions, given lack of python or R experience. I think it is unfair of an admin to downvote my answer, considering that you answered the question yourself.

Comment: I have an experience in R and your code can't run with the data in exemple

Comment: I am not talking about you. I am talking about the person who asked the question. Just super biased and unfair that you had to downvote the question.

Comment: VijayRamesh That is how this site works - if someone doesn't agree with your answer they are able to downvote it.  You don't know who downvoted (so it possibly wasn't @GeoStoneMarten), and there is more than one who has downvoted your answer.  If you are getting downvotes I recommend instead of complaining you refine/improve your answer in a way to attract upvotes.  Please note that the OP isn't asking how to do this in R, they've asked how to do it in Arcpy.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. My question was not stated correctly and i did not include a sample code. (First time asking something here) so it is my fault. Thank you all for your time! -- OP

Comment: @OBMGIS you can used the **edit** link below your question to edit it and add any clarification and new information